# reading key input in batch; %errorlevel% remains zero

Tags: batch-file

I am using this code to scan for q/w/e or r presses.

```
for /l %%a in () do (  
choice /c qwerc /t 1 /d c >nul 
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" (echo q)
if "%errorlevel%"=="2" (echo w)
if "%errorlevel%"=="3" (echo e)
if "%errorlevel%"=="4" (echo r)
)
```

This code can detect presses (i.e. it continues through the loop when i press a key and beeps when i press a key other then q/w/e/r), but '%errerlevel%' remains at zero, rendering my if statements useless. Help? I am new to batch so i really don't have the slightest idea about what the problem might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In batch files, lines and blocks of code (code inside parenthesis) are first parsed and the executed. During the parse phase, all variable read operations are removed, replaced with the value in the variable *before* the code starts to execute. So, if the value in the variable changes while the code in the line/block executes, this new value is not accesible, as there is no read operation on the variable.

The usual way to solve it is enable delayed expansion. This allow the programmer to indicate to the parser that some variable reads should be delayed until the execution time. To do so, syntax to access the variable changes from `%var%` into `!var!`

Without delayed expansion, the read operations to `%errorlevel%` are removed from the code, replaced with the value in the variable when the `for` command is parsed. So the final code executed is

```
for /l %%a in () do (  
    choice /c qwerc /t 1 /d c >nul 
    if "0"=="1" (echo q)
    if "0"=="2" (echo w)
    if "0"=="3" (echo e)
    if "0"=="4" (echo r)
)
```

With delayed expansion it can be solved as

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%a in () do (  
    choice /c qwerc /t 1 /d c >nul 
    if "!errorlevel!"=="1" (echo q)
    if "!errorlevel!"=="2" (echo w)
    if "!errorlevel!"=="3" (echo e)
    if "!errorlevel!"=="4" (echo r)
)
```

Also, in this case, as the value being tested is `errorlevel` you also have the option to use the alternative way of checking it that does not need delayed expansion enabled

```
for /l %%a in () do (  
    choice /c qwerc /t 1 /d c >nul 
    if errorlevel 5 (
        rem c
    ) else if errorlevel 4 (echo r
    ) else if errorlevel 3 (echo e
    ) else if errorlevel 2 (echo w
    ) else (echo q)
)
```

To use this syntax remember to test errorlevel from high to low values, as the condition `if errorlevel n` will be true for errorlevel values greater than or equal to n

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
```

at begin of script.
And

**!errorlevel!**

instead your

%errorlevel%